# How to center canvas javascript, dynamically based on text length

Tags: javascript

I want to center "My TEXT!" no matter the length of the string... As the length of the text gets longer, the x coordinate needs to get less.

How can I get the x length of a string?

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script>
           window.onload = function(){
               var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
               var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
               var imageObj = new Image();
               imageObj.onload = function(){
                   context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
                   context.font = "12pt Arial";
                   context.fillText("My TEXT!", 20, 20);
               };
           imageObj.src = "http://images.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo11w.png"; 
           };
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas width="282px" height="177px" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add this to your code:

```
imageObj.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);

    context.font = "12pt Arial";

    /// set text alignment to center
    context.textAlign = 'center';

    /// draw from center
    context.fillText("My TEXT!", canvas.width * 0.5, 20);
};
```

If you need to get the x coordinate itself you'd need to calculate it based on the width of the text (after the font is set):

```
var width = context.measureText(myText).width;
var x = (canvas.width - width) * 0.5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the text alignment.

```
context.textAlign = "center";
context.fillText("My LONGGGGG TEXT!", (canvas.width)/2, 20);
```

Comment: Does changing textAlign change the coordinates to the center of the fillText?

Comment: If you set the co-ordinates to center of the canvas and align text to the "center", the text will be aligned equally on both sides of the x co-ordinate specified. Here the x-co-ordinate is (canvas.width)/2 which is center of the canvas and the text will be aligned equally on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for. http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-text-align/

There's a `textAlign` property on canvas that you can set to "center".  Then start the fill text in the exact middle of the canvas.

**EDIT** - Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mlienau/2MnnC/